# How to read an *.xls file in Octave running on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, octave, odf, xlsread

OS: Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon
Octave: GNU Octave, version 7.1.0

I want to read an *.xls file in Octave running on Linux MINT.

However, when I run the code I get the following message:

`error: 'xlsread' undefined near line 41, column 32

Functions for spreadsheet style I/O (.xls .xlsx .sxc .ods .dbf .wk1
etc.)  are provided in the io package.  See
https://octave.sourceforge.io/io/.

Please read https://www.octave.org/missing.html to learn how you can
contribute missing functionality`

What should I do?

I have installed the io package by running:
`pkg install -forge io` in Octave command window

Comment: Octave packages are now hosted on https://gnu-octave.github.io/packages/ and Octave Forge is no longer maintained. To install the IO package, go to https://gnu-octave.github.io/packages/io/ and copy the string listed in the box at the top of the page and paste that into Octave. If you are using the Ocatve GUI / IDE you can go direct to the github packages site by clicking Help > Octave Packages

Comment: I copied the link:

pkg install "https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/octave/Octave%20Forge%20Packages/Individual%20Package%20Releases/io-2.6.4.tar.gz"

I pasted in GNU-Octave's command window.

I pressed enter button.

I got the following message:
For information about changes from previous versions of the io package, run 'news io'.

I ran again Octave
I ran the code again, however I got the same error message.

Comment: What do you see if you type `pkg list` ?

Comment: Did you type `pkg load io` before you ran your code?

Comment: `pkg install -forge packagename` still works.

Comment: I just typed as you said:

>> pkg load io
>> pkg list
Package Name  | Version | Installation directory
--------------+---------+-----------------------
          io *|   2.6.4 | /home/siou/snap/octave/306/.local/share/octave/api-v57/packages/io-2.6.4

I ran it. All good Sir. Thanks a lot